# Python Pandas still prints ellipsis after setting max columns and row width

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long list which prints out everything as supposed to except one column that prints its rows with ellipsis because it holds a long value

tried:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
```

they both seem to work untill a certain point, both jupyter-notebook and output saved into a log gives the same output.

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCL8t.png)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the right option.

From the documentation:

> display.max_colwidth sets the maximum width of columns. Cells of this length or longer will be truncated with an ellipsis.

> display.max_colwidth : int or None
> The maximum width in characters of a column in the repr of
> a pandas data structure. When the column overflows, a "..."
> placeholder is embedded in the output. A 'None' value means unlimited.
> [default: 50] [currently: 50]

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
print(df)

# Output
0  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```